# How to concatenate two array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

How to concatenate two arrays to a single array? In date position 0 and 1 are both concatenated in loop, my array code below here.

```
Array
(
    [Apr-2019] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [DateUser] => Apr-2019
                    [withdarw_amount] => 4.00
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [current_deposit_amount] => 1.00
                    [current_deposit_table_refer] => 0.00
                    [current_deposit_user_refer] => 0.10
                    [DateUser] => Apr-2019
                )
        )
)
```

like my output:

```
[Apr-2019] => Array
        (
                    [DateUser] => Apr-2019
                    [withdarw_amount] => 4.00
                    [current_deposit_amount] => 1.00
                    [current_deposit_table_refer] => 0.00
                    [current_deposit_user_refer] => 0.10
                    [DateUser] => Apr-2019
        )
```

I have tried to use this code,

```
$data = array_merge($withdrow_amount,$data_casback,$cashbonus_data,$data_discount,$CurrentDeposit);
$months = array();
foreach($data as $date) {
  $month = substr($date['DateUser'], 0, 8);
  $months[$month][] = $date;
}
echo '<pre>'; print_r($months); die;
```

Comment: Not clear. What is the expected output?

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Please show us your attempt to reach the desired goal.

Comment: @Sougata Bose  thank, your answer it's work perfect me

Comment: @Nick  thank, your answer it's work perfect me

Comment: How to this array sort month and year wise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your array, using [`array_merge`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge) with the [splat operator `...`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) to flatten the internal arrays. Note you can't have two `DateUser` keys in an array so one will be deleted; assuming they have the same values as in your data that will not be a problem:

```
$array = array (
    'Apr-2019' => 
    array (
        0 => 
        array (
            'DateUser' => 'Apr-2019',
            'withdarw_amount' => 4.00
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
            'current_deposit_amount' => 1.00,
            'current_deposit_table_refer' => 0.00,
            'current_deposit_user_refer' => 0.10,
            'DateUser' => 'Apr-2019'
        ),
    ),
    'Jun-2019' => 
        array (
            0 => 
            array (
                'DateUser' => 'Jun-2019',
                'withdarw_amount' => 334.00
            ),

        )
);

foreach ($array as &$arr) {
    $arr = array_merge(...$arr);
}
print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [Apr-2019] => Array
        (
            [DateUser] => Apr-2019
            [withdarw_amount] => 4
            [current_deposit_amount] => 1
            [current_deposit_table_refer] => 0
            [current_deposit_user_refer] => 0.1
        )
    [Jun-2019] => Array
        (
            [DateUser] => Jun-2019
            [withdarw_amount] => 334
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/gPmd3)

Comment: How to this array sort month and year wise ?

Comment: @HardikPatel that's probably worth a new question, but basically you would use `uksort` with a function that converted the `Apr-2019` style strings into a `DateTime` object (using `date_create_from_format`) and then sorted on them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple loops also to do that -

```
$new = [];
foreach ($array as $key =>$a) {
    $new[$key] = []; // Define with key
    foreach ($a as $v) {
        $new[$key] += $v; // Concat
    }
}
```

Comment: How to this array output sort month and year wise?

Comment: You can use `usort()` for sorting.